# Autoplay in iDangerous swiper

Tags: jquery

I am using iDangerous swiper in my application

I have three images in my home page.

I want to autoplay the images for every 3 seconds.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-container" style="background: #CCCCCC">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide tips_content2">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="1.jpg"></img><span class="image1">Image 1</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide tips_content1">
                <ul>
                   <li><img src="2.jpg"></img><span class="image2">Image 2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide tips_content">
                <ul>
                <li><img src="3.jpg"></img><span class="image3">Image3</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="pagination"></div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    mode: 'horizontal',
    pagination: '.pagination',
   loop:true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    autoplay:3000,
    freeMode:true,
    paginationElement:'div',
    onSlideNext :function(swiper){
    $('.swiper-active-switch').css('background-color', '#fff');
}
});
</script>
```

The images are getting changed for every 3 seconds.But in the pagination div,there are five dots getting displayed instead of three dots.

Also,the active swiper in the pagination is not getting switched appropriately.

Please Advice.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be because you are having 5 span element in pagination div, can you try removing two span elements from pagination div.

Comment: Thanks.But there are no span elements in the pagination tags.         <div class="pagination"></div> and also I added paginationElement:'div' and there are only three dots are getting displayed now .But now the dot for active page is not getting highlighted and it remains in the first position

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle so that I can check over it

Comment: sorry I cannot create fiddle account from here.but I have updated the code.